# Timestamp a txt file from the output of a command all in 1 line

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to timestamp the filename of the following command however I'm struggling to get it included.

`ping.exe -n 3600 1.1.1.1 | Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_}  >> $ENV:UserProfile\Downloads\pingresult.txt`

I want the output to be "202211081006_pingresult.txt"

Comment: `Get-Date` should be part of your file name instead of part of your output to the file

Comment: `Get-Date` in this command timestamps each ping within the file.  I don't think I can use the same `Get-Date`.

Comment: Then perhaps add another one? `('{0}\Downloads\{1:yyyyMMddHHmm}_pingresult.txt' -f $env:UserProfile , (Get-Date))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same technique you're using for the *content* of your file for its *name* too, by using `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), and a [custom date-time format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) with `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f):

```
ping.exe -n 3600 1.1.1.1 |
  ForEach-Object { 
    '{0} - {1}' -f (Get-Date), $_ 
  } >> "$HOME\Downloads\$('{0:yyyyMMddHHmm}' -f (Get-Date))_pingresult.txt"
```